# Portsnap error, doesn't work anymore FreeBSD 8.2

Tags: syntax, freebsd

I can't seem to run `portsnap` anymore, there seems to be an error and `/usr/ports/sysutils/portsnap` doesn't exist for a reinstallation.

The error I'm getting when running portsnap is:

```
/usr/sbin/portsnap: line 882: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline' 
/usr/sbin/portsnap: line 882: ' if !'
```

Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error seems to indicate that some other shell is running the script and not sh.

Have a look at this thread: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2008-06/msg00078.html

What happens if you do `sh /usr/sbin/portsnap fetch`?

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks, it turned out I had replaced sh with a different script.